# Как правильно спроектировать нейросеть для игрового бота?

Tags: node.js, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

Существует прототип 2D-онлайн-игры с видом сверху, в которой игрок управляет одним из предложенных танков. Карта состоит из разных блоков с разной степенью разрушаемости. Помимо этого, на карте могут появляться аптечки для починки танка и мины, оставленные другими игроками.

Хотя возможность респавна предусмотрена, нейросеть должна обучаться в процессе игры, не перезагружая всю симуляцию.

Я представляю себе такую реализацию: Бот рендерит себе упрощенную картину мира вокруг себя, записывает это в матрицу, скажем, 96 на 96 пикселей, и кормит этой матрицей `tensorflow.js`, получая на выход 6 сигналов: движение вперед, назад, влево, вправо, выстрел, и установка мины. Если сигнал на выходном нейроне больше 0.5, соответствующее ему действие выполняется.

Всё, казалось бы, хорошо, но в процессе реализации возник ряд вопросов:

1. Какого формата должна быть матрица? Как можно изобразить на ней одновременно танки и сущности в роде мин/снарядов? Учитывая то, что танки могут быть разными, как и снаряды, и против них работают разные тактики.
2. Как показать на изображении, куда повернуты танки на карте? Для прицеливания надо достаточно точно знать этот угол и взаимное расположение объектов на карте.
3. Как бот будет понимать, куда движется танк/снаряд на карте? Ведь прицеливаться тоже надо "на опережение".
4. И, наконец, какие слои должны быть у нейросети и как её правильно обучать? Будет ли сеть совершенствоваться, если поставить её против неё самой?

UPD: Думаю, стоит уточнить, что бот будет запускаться на серверной стороне. Серверная часть написана на Node.js.

Кстати, вот сама игра: http://remote.lazyhome.ru/tanks-online